# problem to reach a field in a custom template

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is this path correct to reach the custom field `date_final__c`

```
{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems.Product2.Date_Final__c} ?
```

this is the answer i get:

> unexpected token: <

Comment: obviously the custom field is in the Product object. pardon!

Comment: can you post code of entire template? Issue may be somewhere else

Comment: can not go from `Opportunity` to `OpportunityLineItems` since it refers one-to-many. You have to iterate over lineitmes

Comment: i already do @highfive . maybe i am missing smth .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at your merge expression in pieces

```
{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems.Product2.Date_Final__c}
```

`Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems`  -  this returns a list of size 0 ..n of OpportunityLineItems for the given Opportunity

`Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems.Product2` - this is invalid because  `Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems` is a list, and the lookup relationship to `Product2` only works on single objects, not lists.

Now, since this is Visualforce, you may simply need to restructure your markup

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}" var="oli">
    <apex:outputField value ="{!oli.Product2.Date_Final__c}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Now, you are iterating over a list of OLI and can apply lookup relationships to access the `Product2` fields for a given OLI.